# What is the fastest way to find orphans between two large (size ~900K ) Vectors of Strings in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, vector, arraylist, collections

I'm currently working on a Java program that is required to handle large amounts of data. I have two Vectors...

```
        Vector collectionA = new Vector();
        Vector collectionB = new Vector();
```

...and both of them will contain around 900,000 elements during processing.

I need to find all items in collectionB that are not contained in collectionA. Right now, this is how I'm doing it:

```
        for (int i=0;i<collectionA.size();i++) {
            if(!collectionB.contains(collectionA.elementAt(i))){
                // do stuff if orphan is found
            }
        }
```

But this causes the program to run for lots of hours, which is unacceptable.

Is there any way to tune this so that I can cut my running time significantly?

I think I've read once that using ArrayList instead of Vector is faster. Would using ArrayLists instead of Vectors help for this issue?

Comment: If the value cardinality is low: Keep two sets. One for colA and another for colB. Everytime you add/replace/remove something from each one, update these two sets. Usem them to diff them. If the cardinality is high, I don't know :-)

Comment: Changed 900T to 900K. The latter is likely to be read as terabytes and I'm pretty certain your vectors won't be that big :-)

Comment: lol paxdiablo I was supposed to write 900K initially but opted for 900T since I thought 900K might be read as kilobytes :p

Comment: Mike/Leo: tbh, it's just because I'm not familiar with sets. But if using Sets would greatly improve my running time, then I'll implement the logic using Sets. Thanks!

Comment: If the bottleneck is the comparison itself (for example, your collection holds complex objects that are hard to compare): try to optimize the comparison using some simpler data representation (java quite does that already with the object hashcode(), but maybe you can improve it). As you can see, there are many assumptions for this question :-)

Comment: @Leo It seems OP is not dealing with complex objects as the title mentions vectors of strings.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen oh you're right, I haven't noticed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Use a HashSet for the lookups.

**Explanation:**

Currently your program has to test every item in collectionB to see if it is equal to the item in collectionA that it is currently handling (the `contains()` method will need to check each item).

You should do:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(collectionB);

for (Iterator i = collectionA.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  if (!set.contains(i.next())) {
    // handle
  }
}
```

Using the HashSet will help, because the set will calculate a hash for each element and store the element in a bucket associated with a range of hash values. When checking whether an item is in the set, the hash value of the item will directly identify the bucket the item should be in. Now only the items in that bucket have to be checked.

Using a `SortedSet` like `TreeSet` would also be an improvement over `Vector`, since to find the item, only the position it would be in has tip be checked, instead of all positions. Which `Set` implementation would perform best depends on the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are HashSets different from Sets? Mike and Leo suggested to use Sets, so I was just wondering if they're the same thing as HashSets.

Comment: upvoting this one over the other one because of the explanation provided

Comment: @heisenbergman - HashSet is an implementation of the Set interface (so, yes they are different).  If you want, you can experiment with TreeSet.  Depending on the "shape" of the data, it might be faster than the HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

If ordering of the elements doesn't matter, I would go for [HashSets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), and do it as follows:

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> b = new HashSet<>();

// ...

b.removeAll(a):
```

So in essence, you're removing from set `b` all the elements that are in set `a`, leaving the *asymmetric set difference*. Note that the [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method does modify set `b`, so if that's not what you want, you would need to make a copy first.

---

To find out whether `HashSet` or `TreeSet` is more efficient for this type of operation, I ran the below code with both types, and used Guava's [`Stopwatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) to measure execution time.

```
@Test
public void perf() {
    Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i=0; i < 900000; i++) {
        String uuidA = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String uuidB = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        setA.add(uuidA);
        setB.add(uuidB);
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    setB.removeAll(setA);

    System.out.println(stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```

On my modest development machine, using Oracle JDK 7, the `TreeSet` variant is about 4 times slower (~450ms) than the `HashSet` variant (~105ms).

Comment: Thank you for the sample code Robby. I'll try this out.